# SQL Group By min(len())

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select min(length(city)), city
from station
group by min(length(city));

select max(length(city)), city
from station
group by min(length(city));


output = ERROR 1056 (42000) at line 1: Can't group on 'min(length(city))'
```

I am trying to get minimum and maximum char length with city name. I thought this algorithm will be okay.

Why ı can't group on `min(length(city))`

Comment: Your title says "order by" but the queries say "group by".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to group by an aggregate function. Aggregate functions are called *after* grouping, to calculate something for all the rows in the group (such as a sum total).

You can use a subquery to calculate an aggregate for the entire table. Then you can compare this with individual rows.

```
SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS length
FROM station
WHERE LENGTH(city) = (SELECT MIN(length(city)) FROM station);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
 SELECT CITY , LENGTH(city) AS length
    FROM STATION
    WHERE LENGTH(CITY)  
          IN (
          SELECT  MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) 
          FROM STATION
          UNION 
          SELECT  MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) 
          FROM STATION )
```